# Pandas: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Dataframes that store data about products procured in a store. `df1` stores data about the store name, product id, product name and the date when the purchase was made. `df2` stores data about product id, product name and the type. I am trying to update `df2` with the Date recevied value in `df1` but only for products of type `P`.

Given below are views of the dataframe and what I tried doing.

`df1`:

```
StoreName,ProdId,ProdName,DateReceived
Store A,P1,Prod1,2018-05-01
Store A,P2,Prod2,2018-05-02
Store B,P1,Prod1,2018-05-04
```

`df2`:

```
DateRecived,ProdId,ProdName,Type

,P1,Prod1,P
,P2,Prod2,P
,P3,Prod3,S
```

Script:

```
df2['DateRecived'] = df2['ProdId'].map(df1.set_index('ProdId')['StoreName']).df2['Type'] == 'P'
```

Running this throws the below error:

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Could anyone help me modify the script so that I am able to filter out value by `Store Name` and `Prod Name` and get `df2` populated with the `DateReceived` value. Thanks.

Comment: @jezrael, I was trying to filter out the Dataframe by Type = P and hence tried to append that to the end of the condition. Basically the output I am looking for is to filter by Store Name, Product Name and Type = P as part of the output..

Comment: yes, just realised it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem is duplicates - `P1` product is twice:

```
s = df1.set_index('ProdId')['StoreName']
print (s)

ProdId
P1    Store A
P2    Store A
P1    Store B
Name: StoreName, dtype: object
```

So need unique values, [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) keep only first value:

```
s = df1.drop_duplicates('ProdId').set_index('ProdId')['StoreName']
print (s)
ProdId
P1    Store A
P2    Store A
Name: StoreName, dtype: object
```

And then is possible repalce by boolean mask:

```
mask = df2['Type'] == 'P'
df2['DateRecived'] = df2['DateRecived'].mask(mask, df2['ProdId'].map(s))
print (df2)
  DateRecived ProdId ProdName Type
0     Store A     P1    Prod1    P
1     Store A     P2    Prod2    P
2         NaN     P3    Prod3    S
```

---

```
df2.loc[mask, 'DateRecived'] = df2.loc[mask, 'ProdId'].map(s)
print (df2)
  DateRecived ProdId ProdName Type
0     Store A     P1    Prod1    P
1     Store A     P2    Prod2    P
2         NaN     P3    Prod3    S
```

Comment: could I please ask for one more help on this. If I were to say we had one more column called Sub-Category in df1 and would like to have that included in the final Dataframe how could we modify this. Thanks..

Comment: @darkhorse - I think simpliest is `s1 = df1.drop_duplicates('ProdId').set_index('ProdId')['Sub-Category']
df2.loc[mask, 'Sub-Category'] = df2.loc[mask, 'ProdId'].map(s1)`