# Map to a list or another list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (`df1`) with a column of lists (`Versions`) and I need to create another column that gives a name to those lists (`Ver_Groups`).

I created another dataframe (`df2`) with unique values and was going to map it to the first dataframe (`df1`), matching on the list.

#### Issue

But then I following error:

> Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects.

#### My code

```py
df1['Ver_Groups'] = df1['Versions'].map(df2.set_index('Versions')['Ver_Groups'])
```

Input dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Versions': [['M'], ['M', 'N'], ['M', 'P'], ['M'], ['N', 'M'], ['P', 'M']]})
```

#### Expected `df1` results

[image]

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Could you show a small example of what `df1` looks like *before*, as well as after? And could you show it *as text*, formatted like code, the way it would appear in a terminal window?

Comment: The reindexing fails because there are duplicates in column `Versions` (759 duplicated by 726, 124 by 498, 954 by 129). See [answered question on same error-message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50389096/pandas-invalidindexerror-reindexing-only-valid-with-uniquely-valued-index-obje)

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply `join` method on `Versions` column:

```
df1['Ver_Groups'] = df1['Versions'].apply('&'.join)
```

Output:

```
    Versions   Ver_Groups
0      [M]          M
1   [M, N]        M&N
2   [M, P]        M&P
3      [M]          M
4   [M, N]        M&N
5   [M, P]        M&P
```

If lists in `Versions` have at most two items, we can do the following. Basically, just create a set of viable version groups and apply it back to `Ver_Groups` column.

```
ver_set = set()
df1['Ver_Groups'] = df1['Versions'].apply('&'.join)
for i in df1['Ver_Groups']:
    if not set((i,i[::-1])).intersection(ver_set):
        ver_set.add(i)
df['Ver_Groups'] = df1['Ver_Groups'].apply(lambda x: x if x in ver_set else x[::-1])
```

Output:

```
  Versions Ver_Groups
0      [M]          M
1   [M, N]        M&N
2   [M, P]        M&P
3      [M]          M
4   [N, M]        M&N
5   [P, M]        M&P
```

Comment: That's a good option, but they won't always be in that order. Sometimes M, P or P, M and it will have to be consistent so it will have to say, M&P.  Also, if I have all three, it has to say "ALL" so I need to know how to give the each combination of lists a specific value.

Comment: This doesn't help me to add something like "ALL" if I had all three letters in a list.  There's got to be something like mapping. I just don't know how to make the connection. v_groups={'M':set('M'), 'M&P':set(['M','P']), 'ALL':set(['M','P','N'])}